# Spark - Group rows in a DataFrame depending on a column.field, then accessing each group independently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, group-by

I have a DataFrame with a structure similar to:

```
 |-- npaDetails: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- additionalInformation: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- couponDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaService: struct (nullable = true)
 |-- npaHeaderData: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaDownloadDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaDownloadTime: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaIssuanceDate: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- npaNumber: string (nullable = true)
```

I was planning to group the rows depending on the field `npaNumber` to later operate over the groups which has more than one element (so groups of rows with same npaNumber). So I wrote the following:

```
df.groupBy($"npaHeaderData.npaNumber") 
  .count()
  .filter("count > 1")
  .foreach { x => println(x) }
```

With the foreach I was expecting to display groups of rows with the same npaNumber, but instead the elements I was displaying was just the npaNumber and the count value:

```
[3487208122633,2]
[5668207771332,3]
[3567207579910,4]
[5768207822303,2]
[9868207960414,7]
```

I also tried the following without success:

```
val groupedDF = df.groupBy($"npaHeaderData.npaNumber").agg($"npaDetails", $"npaHeaderData")
```

But I get an error message:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   expression '`npaHeaderData`' is neither present in the group by, nor
>   is it an aggregate function. Add to group by or wrap in first() (or
>   first_value) if you don't care which value you get.;; Aggregate
>   [npaHeaderData#6.npaNumber], [npaHeaderData#6.npaNumber AS
>   npaNumber#36, npaHeaderData#6]

How can I access/operate independently with each group of rows, which have been grouped by a column.attribute in the dataframe?

Just in case it is relevant, the next operation I am planning to perform over those groups of rows is a order by, based on `npaHeaderData.npaIssuanceDate`

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Aggregations` would **not** preserve the original rows, instead it will aggregate all the rows in the grouped data and give you one aggregated row only. And you will have only those columns used in `groupBy` and `agg` functions.

If you are intending to preserve all the rows and all the columns, you should go with `withColumn` api and use `Window` function.

```
df.withColumn("count", count($"npaHeaderData").over(Window.partitionBy("npaHeaderData.npaNumber")))
    .filter($"count">1)
```

This should give you all the rows of grouped `dataframe` and with all the columns + `count` column which is going to `filter` all the rows whose count is > 1. If you don't want `count` column, you can use `.drop("count")`

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks. For those who want to add this solution it was necessary the following two imports: import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window AND 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

Comment: yes you are right :) thanks for the acceptance and an upvote :)

Comment: Just one extra thing I would like to confirm. I case I were grouping the rows depending on two fields instead of one, and following the schema of the question, should I just write: Window.partitionBy("npaHeaderData.npaNumber","npaDetails.npa‌​Service") I mean in case I would like to group rows which has value of npaNumber and same value of npaService? Could you confirm I understood correctly how Window.partitionBy works.